# StoryBoard TableViews

Tags: ios5, tableview, storyboard

i created a tableview with a list of abbreviations in storyboards by duplicating a cell and basically editing it. The problem is, after creating all the abbreviations i wanted to add an index or search bar to easily navigate to the sections,  but from all the tutorials I've read they are created from an array of some sort. Is there a way that i can retrieve all of the info from the tableview or still create a search bar in storyboards??

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

In order to get search to work you need to populate your table in code.
Either by referring to an NSMutableArray or using CoreData etc.

It sounds like you are trying to do everything in Storyboards/Interface Builder.
At some point you are going to have to dive into the code side of it because Interface builder will only take you a fraction of the way.

I suggest you google some tutorials on how to do Table Views in code and you'll be able to figure all of this out.